# Why is the existence of large cardinals believed to be true?

Tags: set-theory, large-cardinals

I am in the middle of watching a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nVF4N1Ix5WI) of a presentation given by W. Woodin about the continuum hypothesis. This is not really something I know about, but I am confused by one of the slides (at 22:23 in the linked video). It says:

---

**Theorem (Scott)** Assume $V=L$. Then there are no measurable cardinals.

*> (there are no (genuine) large cardinals)*

**(meta) Corollary** The axiom $V=L$ is false.

---

Basically, I am confused as to why the non-existence of large cardinals is believed to be 'false'. From what I know large cardinals axioms are a *useful* thing to have, but I don't really understand why not allowing them is not just 'problematic', but 'wrong enough' to warrant that sort-of-corollary?

Comment: Incidentally, Woodin's philosophical stance here is by no means universal. I certainly wouldn't conclude $V\not=L$ from Scott's result (even if I were a set-theoretic Platonist or similar, which I'm not).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44095/arguments-against-large-cardinals

Comment: @Noah It is very near universal, though.

Comment: Wait, what do you mean "true"? True *where*?

Comment: One surprising point is that large cardinals have implications on "small sets". If there is a proper class of Woodin cardinals, then not only projective sets are **very** well-behaved (e.g. they are all measurable, etc.), but you cannot even change these properties via forcing. And we also know that these kind of statements are equivalent to the existence of, or at least consistency of, large cardinals. So if you expect "reasonably definable sets" to be "reasonable", you sort of have to assume the existence of large cardinals.

Comment: (The point in my previous comment is that if you believe there is such thing as "truth", and you expect it to have certain properties, then there are consequences of that, and you would also seek axioms which reinforce that truth, rather than contradict it. To that end, large cardinal axioms are regarded as true when they agree with these notions. This is why people who strongly feel that the HOD Conjecture *should be true* will tell you that Reinhardt cardinals are inconsistent even without choice, or people who reject choiceless universes as "true" would say the same.)

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo I think it depends on what our universe is. Among set theorists, certainly; among logicians, I'm not sure.